# Result of Detached Criteria Query is Attached

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am trying to run the following detached criteria query:

```
    def e = new DetachedCriteria(Equipment).build {
        eq('name', ef.name)
    }.get()
```

but when I call `e.isAttached()` immediately afterward, I get `true`.

Background: I know I have an in-memory attached reference to Equipment e, but I want a detached reference to it, so that I can compare old database values to the in-memory set to see what has changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are creating here is not a detached query* - it's an `Equipment` instance.  By adding the `get()` you are executing the query and producing an attached `Equipment` instance.  To create the detached query take away the `get()`:

```
def dQuery = new DetachedCriteria(Equipment).build {
    eq('name', ef.name)
}
```

and then later when you need to execute:

```
def e = dQuery.get()
```

If you want to detach the `Equipment` instance then you could call

```
e.discard()
```

- actually you are creating the detached query - it is just never assigned to anything so it's sort of in the background.

Comment: So a detached query produces attached results?  What is the point of a detached query, then?  According to the [grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/discard.html), discard simply undoes any unpersisted changes to an object.  My understanding of detaching is that changes to the object will not affect attached instances of the same data... am I missing something?

Comment: The detached query is a way to create a query for future use - the query itself is not attached to the particular session it is created in.  Once you execute the query (with `get() or list()`) it attaches and executes.  The instances it brings back are attached just as if you had created and run the query at the same time. Also  `discard` does reset any changes, but it also detaches the instance.  So if you `discard` as soon as you retrieve the instance you will just have a detached instance that doesn't persist changes to the database.

Comment: Also GORM can be a tricky bugger when talking about persistence.  Peter Ledbrook has a great series about GORM Gotchas http://blog.springsource.org/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/